# inconsistency in inline-block

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I mixed `div` and `img` up in an `inline-block`, but the div is not inline with the other images. Can you please tell me why and how to fix it?

My code:

```css
.floating-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
.after-box {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
 <h2>The New Way - using inline-block</h2>
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oBB6.png">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnTG7.jpg">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oBB6.png">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnTG7.jpg">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oBB6.png">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnTG7.jpg">
<div class="floating-box">Yeah</div>
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oBB6.png">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnTG7.jpg">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oBB6.png">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnTG7.jpg">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oBB6.png">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnTG7.jpg">
<div class="after-box">Another box, after the floating boxes...</div>
```

Comment: I think you'll probably need to explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: @Teemu The div is not inline with the other images

Comment: Though the code doesn't work, communication should still be working ; ).

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the css property `vertical-align: top;` to align top of all the elements.

Example Snippet:

```css
.floating-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.after-box {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h2>The New Way - using inline-block</h2>
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oBB6.png">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnTG7.jpg">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oBB6.png">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnTG7.jpg">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oBB6.png">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnTG7.jpg">
<div class="floating-box">Yeah</div>
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oBB6.png">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnTG7.jpg">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oBB6.png">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnTG7.jpg">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oBB6.png">
<img class="floating-box" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnTG7.jpg">
<div class="after-box">Another box, after the floating boxes...</div>
```

Read about vertical-align property in detail [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)